# Please help in this SQL query

Tags: sql, database

My database is like this -

There are multiple Courses in a College. A Course is further divided into multiple streams. A stream has multiple Subjects , which in turn has multiple Topics. Finally there are multiple Notes for a Topic,Stream, Subject and Topic.

Course -> Streams -> Subjects -> Topics -> Notes

I want to write a select query to get a bird-eye view of the number of notes in the given Course.
I want this -

MBA (Total Notes Count - 5)                                                       - Course

HR (Total Notes Count - 5)                                                        - Streams

Sub A  (Total Notes Count - 5)                                          - Subject

Topic 1  (Total Notes Count - 2)                                    - Topic

Topic 2 (Total Notes Count - 3)

In the above example, Sub A and Sub B has a total of 5 notes which is getting shown against HR.

Please help me in writing query for this. The query needs to be very fast.

I am attaching my script. I can think of writing multiple sub queries but I dont think that will be an optimized method.

```
select MC.CourseName,MS.StreamName,MSub.SubjectName,MT.TopicName,MN.NoteName
from Master_Course MC
JOIN Master_Stream MS ON MC.CourseId = MS.CourseId
JOIN Master_Subject MSub ON MS.StreamId = MSub.StreamId
JOIN Master_Topics MT ON MSub.SubjectId = MT.SubjectId
JOIN Master_Notes MN ON MT.TopicId = MN.TopicId
```

Comment: simple join will do... no need to do any tricky thing I guess, looks straight forward.

Comment: Can you please post table definitions and the expected result? Is it correct that you want to see the number of notes at all levels of the hierarchy? If so, you will need to do outerjoins on subqueries. I wouldn't worry about performance until you get it to return the data you want.

Comment: I have edited my question. I actually want to know the count for every Course, Stream, Subject, and Topic.

Comment: Yes @NevilleK I want to know the number at every level of hierarchy.

Comment: @NevilleK table definitions are quite simple with just id and name.. if u still need it, I can post that..

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
 MC.CourseName,
 MCN.NoteCount
 MS.StreamName,
 MS.NoteCount
 MSub.SubjectName,
 MT.TopicName,
 MN.NoteName
from Master_Course MC
JOIN 
   (select MasterCourseID, count(*) as NoteCount
        from Master_Course MC
        JOIN Master_Stream MS ON MC.CourseId = MS.CourseId
        JOIN Master_Subject MSub ON MS.StreamId = MSub.StreamId
        JOIN Master_Topics MT ON MSub.SubjectId = MT.SubjectId
        JOIN Master_Notes MN ON MT.TopicId = MN.TopicId
        JOIN Master_Stream MS ON MC.CourseId = MS.CourseId) MCN 
        on MC.MasterCourseID = MCN.MasterCourseID
 JOIN Master_Subject MSub ON MS.StreamId = MSub.StreamId
JOIN Master_Topics MT ON MSub.SubjectId = MT.SubjectId
JOIN Master_Notes MN ON MT.TopicId = MN.TopicId
```

See subquery for getting top-level note count; you'll need to repeat this for each level of the hierarchy.

It should be pretty fast, as you're joining on primary keys and counting; if it runs too slowly, you might capture the note count logic in a (materialized) view.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you want. However, you can get some counting adding the following after your JOIN statements:

```
GROUP BY CourseID, StreamID, SubjectID, TopicID WITH ROLLUP
```

or

```
GROUP BY CourseID, StreamID, SubjectID, TopicID WITH CUBE
```

This is of course the guessed names of you unique identifiers. The differences between ROLLUP and CUBE is:

ROLLUP will count the following combinations:

```
CourseID, StreamID, SubjectID, TopicID
CourseID, StreamID, SubjectID
CourseID, StreamID
CourseID
```

CUBE will do all combination of one to all four of the given elements like

```
CourseID
CourseID, SubjectID
StreamID, SubjectID, TopicID
....
```

So if you need all combinations anyway, use CUBE, else use ROLLUP.
ROLLUP will give you a count of all unique courses, all unique combinations with the same CourseID and StreamID (but with different SubjectID and TopicID) and so on for CourseID, StreamID and SubjectID and all four.

I hope that this is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the "ID" of each table is PK, that is optimized, only left count in your query:

```
select count(Master_Notes.columnX) FROM 
from Master_Course MC
JOIN Master_Stream MS ON MC.CourseId = MS.CourseId
JOIN Master_Subject MSub ON MS.StreamId = MSub.StreamId
JOIN Master_Topics MT ON MSub.SubjectId = MT.SubjectId
JOIN Master_Notes MN ON MT.TopicId = MN.TopicId
WHERE Master_Course.columnY = Z
```